# How can I find out the OS version and CPU type in Windows CE?

Tags: windows

How can I find out the OS version and CPU type in Windows CE, without disassembling the device or compiling any extra software?

Answer (score 16):

1. From the **Start** menu go to **Settings** then **Control Panel**.

[image]

2. Start **System**.

[image]

3. There are two sections **Computer**: and **System**:. Under **Computer** section is the Windows CE version number and under **System** section is the Processor Type.

[image]

*Note*: The graphics and menu arrangements may be different among various Win CE versions, but the general guide remains the same. On the more recent versions of Windows CE, the Processor Type information may not be completely on the screen, so you may need to copy the text and paste it to some other Windows that has a text field (such as the **Run** menu)

[Source (long lost)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120306173949/https://netcfwince200.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20find%20out%20%20the%20Windows%20CE%20version%20and%20Processor%20Type%20on%20your%20device.&referringTitle=Home)